# Filter a Realm list inside objects

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Say I have the following objects in `Realm`:

```
class Student: Object{
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    let subjects = List<Subject>()
}

class Subject: Object{
    @objc dynamic var name: String = "" 
    @objc dynamic var grade: String = "" // A, B, C, etc
}
```

I want to query students, but I want only to have `subjects` that have grade A only.

Ex, if I have the following saved in Realm:

```
Student 1, subjects = [("math", "A"), ("Science", "B")]
Student 2, subjects = [("math", "C"), ("Science", "A")]
Student 3, subjects = [("math", "B"), ("Science", "C")]
```

I want students with their grades equal to A. The results should return the following:

```
Student 1, subjects = [("math", "A")]
Student 2, subjects = [("Science", "A")]
```

So I end up with Realm Results of type `Student` butt all the `subjects`'s grades equal to A. 
Is that possible in Realm DB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Realm Filter objects in a list of a relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37193959/ios-realm-filter-objects-in-a-list-of-a-relationship)

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I don't think this question is a duplicate. The link is a question about a query three level deep and this question is a query of an objects list.

Answer (score 0):

You can't exactly get there from here - you will need a small interim step to get the desired output.

To start with you can query a List using the ANY aggregate function. So to get students who have any grades of 'A' you can do this.

```
let studentResults = realm.objects(Student.self).filter("ANY subjects.grade == 'A'")
```

The problem lies in that the results are students who have literally ANY grades of A, and the returned results are the *student* objects with all of their grades in their list.

Fortunately we can also apply a filter directly to a list. So, we're going to iterate over each student returned in studentResults and then filter their list property for just the subjects where they received and 'A'. Like this

```
let studentResults = realm.objects(Student.self).filter("ANY subjects.grade == 'A'")
for student in studentResults {
    let gradeAResults = student.subjects.filter("grade == 'A'")

    for grades in gradeAResults {
        print(student.name, grades.name, grades.grade)
    }
}
```

and the out is

```
student 1 math A
student 2 Science A
```

Note this will also output the students name multiple times where a they may have received an 'A' in more than one subject.

Comment: Thanks @Jay for suggesting this one but I don't want to iterate over my results, what I am aiming for is an updated Realm Results using some filtration that satisfy my criteria. Something supported by Realm itself

Comment: @MohamMadSalah Unfortunately, there isn't a direct query like you're seeking. I believe for your use case my solution is not only the simplest but also the fastest. What's the issue with an iteration - even with thousands of results, that loop will only take a fraction of a second.

Comment: @MohamMadSalah Check out my other answer - it does essentially the same thing with without any kind of iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a separate answer which does answer the question but the OP doesn't want any kind of iteration. So here's another possibility using a different approach.

For this approach we are going to add a reference in every subject taken that links back to the student who took that subject. So the student model now looks like this

```
class Subject: Object{
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var grade: String = "" // A, B, C, etc
    @objc dynamic var studentRef: Student!
}
```

We create a student object:

```
let student = Student()
student.name = "Henry"
```

and then the subjects they take, and their grades are created, with a reference back to the student that took that subject:

```
let subject = Subject()
subject.name = "math"
subject.grade = "A"
subject.studentRef = student
```

Our query to return all students that received a grade of 'A' on any subject is this

```
let gradeAResults = realm.objects(Subject.self).filter("grade == 'A'")
for subject in gradeAResults {
    print(subject.name, subject.grade, subject.studentRef.name)
}
```

and the output would be

```
math A Henry
Science A Pete
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this predicate:

```
SUBQUERY(subjects, $subject, $subject.grade == 'A').@count == subjects.@count
```

Usage:

```swift
let students = realm.objects(Student.self).filter("SUBQUERY(subjects, $subject, $subject.grade == 'A').@count == subjects.@count")
```

It counts the number of subjects of grade A then compares it to the total number of subjects for that student, if it's the same number, then it means that this student has only grade A subjects.

I have not tested it, but it should works.

Comment: Thanks, @Vin, I tried yours, but it doesn't filter the list of subjects, it filters the `Students`

Comment: Alright I misunderstood your question. You want to retrieve a list of students with pre-filtered subjects (only grade A ones), unfortunately, I don't think this is something possible with Realm.