# swift NSPredicate Data (Struct)

Tags: swift, realm

In realm i saving struct data like this

```
class DBDialogs: Object {
    @objc dynamic var userId = 0
    @objc dynamic var initials = ""
    @objc private dynamic var structData:Data? = nil
    var Info : User? {
        get {
            if let data = structData {
                do {
                    return try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
                }catch {
                    return nil
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            structData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
        }
    }
}
struct User : Codable {
var pk : Int?
var email : String?
var brand : String?
var discs : Discs?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case pk = "pk"
    case email = "email"
    case brand = "brand"
    case discs = "discs"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    pk = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .pk)
    email = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .email)
    brand = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .brand)
    discs = try values.decodeIfPresent(Discs.self, forKey: .discs)
}

}
```

how can i filter the struct data ? trying something like this, but i get the error (`Unable to parse the format string "Info?.brand == %@"`)

```
var dbDialogsArray: Results<DBDialogs>?
var dbDialogsMethods = DBDialogsMethods()
....

class DBDialogsMethods { // also in this class i will write to realm, update, delete and etc
    var realm: Realm!
    func getArray() -> Results<DBDialogs> {
        return realm.objects(DBDialogs.self)
    }
}

....

let realm = try! Realm()
dbDialogsMethods.realm = realm
dbDialogsArray = dbDialogsMethods.getArray()
...

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "Info?.brand = %@", brandField.text!)
let filteredDialogs = dbDialogsArray?.filter(predicate)
```

i have array DBDialogs, i need to filter the array by fields in Info (structData)

Why i do with NSPredicate : 
I have several fields by which I filter data (fields for filtering are selected manually in the application), using NSPredicate I can filter multiple fields that the user chose in the app, something like this

```
var stringPredicate = Dictionary <String, NSObject> ()
stringPredicate ["brand"] = brand.text! as NSObject
var generalPredicates = [NSPredicate] ()
        for (key, value) in stringPredicate {
            let predicate = NSPredicate (format: "% K =% @", key, value)
            generalPredicates.append (predicate)
        }
```

and filter everything at once, I don’t know how to do filtering in another way with the condition that you need to filter only those fields that the user selected in the application

Comment: What exactly do you want to filter?

Comment: @Sh_Khan  nope. it not the array

Comment: @PGDev  i need to filter the array (DBDialogs) by fields in Info (structData)

Comment: What is DBDialogs?

Comment: @alexking how are you using that `predicate`, what's `dbDialogsArray`? And what error do you get?

Comment: @alexking May be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37199070/1140335) will help you?

Comment: @alexking BTW What is `Info?.brand`?

Comment: @alexking I mean why `"Info?.brand = %@"` ? On the left side you have to pass the key. Why there is a question mark?

Comment: @TheTiger cuz `Info` is the optional value, trying without question mark and get the error `'Property 'Info' not found in object of type 'DBDialogs'`

Comment: @alexking Did you try by for loop instead of predicate?

Comment: @TheTiger yep. i doing now with `filter(_ isIncluded and if else` - but is not comfortable. a lot of checks

Comment: Can you provide an example of what exactly you are trying to filter? Please update your question with that information. and while you're there, can you clean up the code formatting as it's difficult to read.