# How to set NSPredicate in Realm to find totalPrice > X?

Tags: swift, realm, nspredicate

Here is a realm models:

```
final class OrderObject: Object {
   @Persisted var items: List<OrderItemObject>
}
    
final class OrderItemObject: EmbeddedObject {
   @Persisted var price: Decimal128
   @Persisted var count: Int
}
```

How can I find a total items price (price * count) > than some number, for example 50? Using NSPredicate in OrderObject

Comment: The question is a little unclear. Are you asking how to get a total for single item contained in the `items` List or for a series of items in that List? The words *total items* is the confusing part, items is plural. Also how does the NSPredicate play a role? Are you attempting to filter the list as well? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @Jay I just need to give a some kind of predicate to get OrderObject's items more than 50$ (example), to get it I have to multiply OrderItemObject's price with count
Is there any other ways to find it except NSPredicate?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [iOS Realm Filter objects in a list of a relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37193959/ios-realm-filter-objects-in-a-list-of-a-relationship)?

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of ways to filter the list but most importantly, you can't perform math within a realm filter on a computed property (it's not persisted). That means to use a filter the data must exist in Realm.

One option is to use computed property backing variables. This technique will store the price, count and the total values in realm but your app interfaces with the object through computed vars that update those backing vars as they change.

Here's a new OrderItemObject model

```
class OrderItemObject: EmbeddedObject {
    @objc private dynamic var _price: Decimal128 = 0.0
    @objc private dynamic var _count: Int = 0
    @objc private dynamic var _total: Decimal128 = 0.0

    var price: Decimal128 {
        get {
            return self._price
        }
        set {
            _price = newValue
            self._total = newValue * Decimal128(value: self._count)
        }
    }

    var count: Int {
        get {
            return self._count
        }
        set {
            self._count = newValue
            self._total = Decimal128(value: newValue) * self._price
        }
    }

    var total: Decimal128 {
        get {
            return self._total
        }
    }
}
```

The _price and _count are private so they cannot be accessed from outside the model, as well as the _total. With this configuration, if your app changes the price or count, it updates the backing _total var.

Then the filter is super easy

```
let items = order.items.filter("_total > 50")
```

There are a number of other options as well.

Keep in mind this solution needs to incorporate a realm.write if you are updating an existing persisted object.